# how can I create two different "about-us " page for two themes and single store view

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, cms

I have two themes (desktop and mobile) for a single store view.
I want to create two different "about-us" page for the two themes.

There are also lot of other **cms pages** which are **to be shown in both themes** with different styles.

So should I create each cms page two times (one for desktop and other for mobile) ?
 Or
 is there any other methods to show the same cms page in desktop and in mobile with different look ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it cannot be done with a native Magento install.

My suggestion is to create only one page and split the content.

The first part of the page is the structure of your page on your desktop theme.
The second part is the structure on your mobile theme.

Then as your themes have different css, you display/hide the part of your page that matches the theme.

A little bit hacky but I guess it will save you a lot of time instead of developping a module trying to implement theme based pages.

Comment: it seems a good idea.ok.one more thing...in which phtml file the cms page get rendered. I modified cms/content.phtml, but nothing happened.

Comment: The cms page are not rendered the same way as other pages. The Mage_Cms_Block_Page block rewrites the _toHtml function and uses a template processor to return the page HTML.

Comment: There are many other cms pages too. Should I apply the same trick for all of them ?

Comment: @KishorePatra yes as I said that's the only native way of doing it